# How to exclude traffic with a Regex in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have these three types of pages I need to make a regex expression for each of them in GA. This is what I have so far:

- /destinations/ -> ^/destinations$
- /destinations/manchester/ -> Not sure how to get a REGEX for this one
- /destinations/manchester/imperial-museum -> ^/destinos/.*/.*

Could someone let me know if they are correct, and the one I am missing give me a hint please?

Thanks so much. Beatriz

Comment: Can you instead give us a set of rules for which types of paths should match, and which should not?  If you really want to match there three literal paths, then you may just use a regex with an alternation (though I doubt that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following (depending on the Regex engine, but generally this should work out):

```
(destinations)(.manchester)?(.imperial-museum)?
```